# Cannot write png of plot in R on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, r, linux, heroku

I can save a plot as a `.png` in R locally (on a mac) with

```
png("file.png"); plot(0); dev.off()
```

But when I run this R code on linux (from the R interpreter inside a rails app on heroku), nothing happens, and no file is written

### What I know so far

Heroku's storage is ephemeral, but I have tested `write.csv(iris, "myfile.csv")` and it works perfectly fine - the file writes and is visible inside the rails app directory using `Dir.entries(Dir.pwd)`

I came across [this](https://superuser.com/questions/603744/why-is-r-having-trouble-rendering-plots-to-a-png-file) question/answer, but running `capabilities()` in the R interpreter on heroku as the answer suggests returns TRUE for png (suggesting it should be able to write `.png`)

So in summary, other files write, and it would appear that a png should write, but it doesn't, and I can't work out why

Comment: "I have tested `write.csv(iris, "myfile.csv")` and it works perfectly fine"—note that this may not do what you think it does. `myfile.csv` will be lost as soon as your dyno restarts, and that happens frequently. If you need anything beyond very temporary storage you should use something like Amazon S3.

Comment: [The documentation for `png()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/grDevices/versions/3.4.1/topics/png) says that the function "will work only if the devices are available and cairo or an X11 display or a macOS display is available". I don't think Heroku provides Cairo or an X11 display by default. You may have to install Cairo. Try starting [here](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/webpolis/heroku-buildpack-cairo).